# Does my Spanish youth mobility visa automatically change to a tourist visa once it expires? or do i need to get a new stamp?

Tags: visas, spain, visa-free-entry, australian-citizens

So I'm about to come to the end of my stay in Spain on my Youth Mobility Visa. Now I just married my partner and we have an appointment to get my residency card here, but it is after the expiry date of my visa. As an Australian, I get a 90-day tourist visa. Do I need to leave the country and get another entry stamp? or once my visa is expired, or do I just move onto the 90-day tourist visa?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your partner's nationality and immigration status.

Comment: If it is your intention to take up residence, you cannot enter as a 'Tourist'. You need to contact Spanish Immigration authorities to find out what Visa you need. If your partner is an EEA citizen then the EEA Family Member route may be possible if you & your partner meet the criteria.

Comment: Australians _do not get tourist visas_ for Schengen. Having an Australian passport _itself_ already allows you to do everything that a short-stay Schengen visa would allow.

Comment: Thank you for all of the responses. My partner is an Italian, but has been living in Barcelona for 5 years and has her residency here. 

Yes, we are applying for the Family member, but our appointment with the ayuntamiento to get my residency card isn't until after my youth mobility visa ends (it has been a long an tedious process).

Tourist visa was probably the wrong wording. But does the passport itself need to be stamped to active the short-term stay (after my youth mobility expires)? or just having the passport is fine?

Thanks again, much appreciated.